# How can I clear logs in docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I've started to try to use docker containers.

After a few weeks of use, I realized that all log messages, since the beginning of the container, are still there. Once this old logs are no longer necessary, is there a way to clear or delete the logs of these containers?

The command to access the logs is `docker logs CONTAINERID`

Is there any way to clear logs

Answer (score 6):

Currently, docker does not have any way to clear container old logs. An [issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9222) had been raised to add this feature, but it was denied.

At this time, you must do it manually.

Container log was at `/var/lib/docker/containers/container-id/container-id-json.log`, you can delete it to make container log clean:

```
$ docker logs flask
172.17.42.1 - - [20/Nov/2014 03:07:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.17.42.1 - - [20/Nov/2014 03:07:20] "GET /static/public/css/common.css?37db3944 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
172.17.42.1 - - [20/Nov/2014 03:07:20] "GET /static/public/images/Character-2x.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
172.17.42.1 - - [20/Nov/2014 03:07:20] "GET /static/public/images/linkedin.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
172.17.42.1 - - [20/Nov/2014 03:07:20] "GET /static/public/images/facebook.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
...
$ mv /var/lib/docker/containers/container-id/container-id-json.log{.bak,}
$ docker logs flask
<empty>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It's a container. Your logs should not be stored inside the container. Configure your services to log to a remote logging server (via syslog or syslog-ng). There are also third parties that run logging services (SumoLogic, Loggly).